# How should I represent mutable boolean state?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

When I have some object with boolean state that can be changed (like a checkbox's checkedness), there are several ways I can expose it.

1. Getter property, Setter method

   ```
   bool IsChecked { get { ... } }
   void SetChecked(bool checked) { ... }
   ```
2. Getter property, Set true method, Set false method

   ```
   bool IsChecked { get { ... } }
   void Check() { ... }
   void Uncheck() { ... }
   ```
3. Getter, setter property

   ```
   bool IsChecked { get { ... } set { ... } }
   ```

Is there a good design or logical reason to use one of these ways in particular? (I apologize if this question is too opinion-based/open-ended)

Answer (score 7):

Idiomatic C# generally favours properties over accessor methods for simple properties, so just use a property unless there is a good reason not to. If there is complex logic in the getter or setter, it may be better to use accessors to avoid breaking the Principle of Least Surprise.

For a canonical example, WPF checkboxes use a property - although a `bool?` to include the "partially checked" state.

Answer (score 2):

Getter/setter properties are the way to go. They are very clear, code-wise, and don't involve adding a weird smell to an entire codebase. Also, tools like Entity Framework use getter/setter pairs to do work, so a property should be more discoverable by tools, IDEs, and frameworks than any hand-rolled solution.

Generally, if you find yourself wanting to improve on the design of very simple operations, like setting variables or looping, resist! :)